# Algorithm for finding matches in multiple arrays by ID Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to write an algorithm that searches for its own route for each stop. Now I do this using several models: first, route variant is looking for its own route (by mv_id), then a different stop is searched for on each flight card (by st_id). All of these models are linked by a common ID. I understand that I need to put everything found in one array and now I have such an algorithm, it loads the list of stops, but after a while it gives me this error. I understand that my algorithm is not correct, but I cannot figure out how to do it as I described above.

my model:

```
class RouteandStopsSearch{
  Routes route;
  List <StopList> stop;
  List <RaceCard> cards;
  ScheduleVariants variant;
}
```

My algorithm:

```
Future<List<RouteandStopsSearch>> searchStops(int mv_id) async {
    List<FlightCard> cards = [];
    List<StopList> stopList = [];
    List<Routes> routes = [];
    List<ScheduleVariants> variants = [];

    cards.addAll(await api.fetchRaceCard(mv_id));
    stopList.addAll(await api.fetchStops());
    routes.addAll(await api.fetchroutes());
    variants.addAll(await api.fetchSchedule());

    print(cards);
    print(stopList);
    List<RouteandStopsSearch> searchStops = [];

    for (Routes routelist in routes) {
      final searchStop = RouteandStopsSearch();

      searchStops.add(searchStop);
      searchStop.route = routelist;

      searchStop.variant = variants.where((element) => element.mrId == routelist.mrId).first;
      List<StopList> currentRoutes = [];
      stopList.forEach((stop) {
        cards.forEach((cards) {
          if(stop.stId == cards.stId){
            return currentRoutes.add(stop);
          }
        });
      });
      return searchStops;
    }
  }

}
```

the error is:

```
I/flutter (23064): [Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'StopList', Instance of 'S

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

Comment: could you describe for what you are using this model, may be there is some better solution for that use.

Comment: @Ruchit hi,yeah, I'll try to explain. I have several parsed models from responses from get requests to the server and I combined them all into one model to write an algorithm for finding stops for each route. I have not come up with a better solution than the code that is written in my question

Comment: nevermind, I solved my issue :)

Comment: nice to here that :)